# Check if an interval contain a value of an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

I am looking for a way to solve the following question with an algorithm. For the sake of the user, the method should be as fast as possible (possibly called thousands of times).

Let I an interval, I = [a, b] (real values).
Let C a real.
Is there any integer k so that ( C + k * 360 ) belong to I. If yes what is the value of k ? If there is multiple k, I want one of them, no matter which one.

I am struggling solving that, yet I am sure there is a simple trick...
I came up with a solution when you are just checking if a multiple of a value belong to an interval, thanks to the quotient of the euclidian division, but this is no help for such case...

Thanks for your ideas.

PS : sorry for my approximative mathematical english language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first check if $b-a \geq 360$; if so, then you're guaranteed to hit the interval. Failing that, note that you're looking to show that $360k \in [a-C,b-C]$. You can divide through by $360$, resulting in $k \in \left[\frac{a-C}{360},\frac{b-C}{360}\right]$. Letting $frac(x)$ represent the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$, if $frac\left(\frac{a-C}{360}\right) > frac\left(\frac{b-C}{360}\right)$, then you will hit a multiple of 360 in this interval; otherwise, not.

In both cases, finding the value $k$ can be done by taking $\left\lceil\frac{a - C}{360}\right\rceil$ (If a value exists in the interval, we know the smallest value valid value has to work).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some testing, it appears that it doesn't work if " a " is exactly a value I am looking for and b - a < 360 . Am I right ? If yes, I also have to test if (a-C)/360 is an integer.

Comment: D'oh, missed the edge case. Yep, that too. Alternatively, you could directly just check whether $360\left\lceil\frac{a - C}{360}\right\rceil + C \leq b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a, b, C$ are known, just check whether the range

$$\left[\frac{a-C}{360}, \frac{b-C}{360}\right]$$

contains any integer.

Comment: Now I realise this was just basic inequalities ... Had gone too far in my head... Thanks anyway ! I would complete by saying that the integer (if one is contained) is the k I was looking for.